# Google Cloud Storage Node.js set metadata file.save

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload an HTML file to Google Cloud Storage and save a URL with it as metadata. The below code is successfully uploading the HTML, but doesn't seem to be setting the metadata, as when I select "Edit metadata" from the drop down for the file in the Cloud Storage web UI, the URL key is not shown, only "Content-Type".

```
await file.save(html, { contentType: "text/html", resumable: false, metadata: { url: "example.com" } });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I worked out that when you want to set custom metadata as well as contentType etc, you need to wrap the whole thing as a meta data key value like this:

```js
await file.save(html, {
      metadata: {
        contentType: "text/html",
        resumable: false,
        metadata: { url: "example.com" },
      },
    });
```

Comment: Please god make my suffering end. Why is it like this. I swear I like being a developer.